# Google Map Caching Issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with google map in my activity.
When i change language for example Chinese in my app settings 
the langauge of map did not change till i reopen my app.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```

i searched a lot about this issue i found that it is google map caching issue but did not found any solution.

Comment: Have you tried to handle this in the onConfigurationChanged Activity method?

Comment: i tried this but not working .....even it is not working in case i reopen activity ...it only works on app reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I can think about 2 options to solve this:

1. Calling setContentView in the onConfigurationChanged method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       if (language_changed){//pseudo_code
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            //now you need to do again all the findViewById call
       }
   }
   ```

---

2. Restart the activity in the onConfigurationChanged method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       if (language_changed){//pseudo_code
            startActivity(CurrentActivity.this, CurrentActivity.class);
            finish();
       }
   }
   ```

I've not tested this, but maybe it's a starting point to try to solve your problem.

Don't forget to add `android:configChanges="locale"` to your activity tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to let the system know that you want to handle Locale changes by yourself. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) if needed

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working ... i already tried it..even when i manually restart activity it is not working ... only works in case of app reopen

Comment: Have you added the configChanges attribute in the activity tag? Read the last 2 lines of my answer

Comment: I can say for sure that you are doing something wrong somewhere. There is no way you can't handle a map locale change. Good luck and debug your code more ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadcastReceiver with LOCALE_CHANGED Intent to detect setting change, and then update your view (Map view or total layout).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

```
public class LocaleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public LocaleReceiver() {}

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        // Call a method to trigger view refreshing here
        }
    }
}
```